# Getting "cpio: Bad magic" when trying to rpm install into a mounted Logical Volume

Tags: fedora, rpm, xen, cpio

I am trying to follow the [Xen guide](http://book.xen.prgmr.com/mediawiki/index.php/Chapter_3:_Provisioning_domUs#Using_the_Package_Management_System_with_an_Alternate_Root) to provision a domU using package installation of the Fedora 15 release (the dom0 is CentOS 5.6). I've run the rpm install command with an alternate root to a mounted root LV, but I keep running into this issue:

```
# rpm -ivh --nodeps --root /mnt/fedRoot fedora-release-15-1.noarch.rpm 
warning: fedora-release-15-1.noarch.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 signature: NOKEY, key ID 069c8460
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:fedora-release         ########################################### [100%]
error: unpacking of archive failed: cpio: Bad magic
```

I'm not sure where to begin with troubleshooting this.

As I understand it, rpm reads the "root" filesystem (which I've designated to the mounted drive) and bases its verification and install directory structure based on the "root" system. What is the `cpio: Bad magic` bit? Any recommendations for making this rpm install work? let me know if more information is needed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with fedora 13 (I think that version anyway), RPMs started using sha256 checksums instead of md5. RHEL5/Centos5 do not support that.
You need to add `--nomd5` to your rpm install command.

Comment: @Patrick... Thanks for the info, I have been findding alot of information that is pointing to the rpm program itself. I will try the `--nomd5` flag when I get home from work today. If that doesnt work I think I am going to need to compile a version of rpm that has all the bits needed for this :( I will update when I have a result.

Comment: unfortunately that didnt work... thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: hrm, interesting as I've had that solve it for me. Sorry for the incorrect suggestion :-/

Comment: no worries... I am thinking it may have something to do with the fact that I am installing Fedora using the package management from within CentOS. I have run a dependency test and posted another [question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15006/can-rpm-handle-an-install-of-another-os-into-another-logical-volume) regarding that result.